# Should my child's name contain "Inn"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, names, nicknames

I have a simple but important question about naming my first child.

I named her, as Jae-in Kim. (pronunciation is , of course, same as Jane in English name) but it is so common that hundreds, maybe thousands of people have the name Jae-in here in Korea, so, I want spell her name Jae-inn Kim (double ‘n’ in inn) for the uniqueness. but as you know, the word “inn” has meaning a kind of accommodation.

From a point of view in US/English cultures, is it ridiculous/funny that a name includes *Inn?* Or is it okay?

Since English isn’t my native language, it's hard for me to figure out its nuance.

Comment: Hi JungJoon--I think that this question might be off topic for the site.

Comment: I think this is a little off-topic, as it involves more opinion rather than a direct question & answer.  But for what it's worth, I wouldn't think anything odd about Jae-inn.

Comment: @simchona // thanks for your advice, but, I don't know where the site is for question about english-cultures. I thought English language include English cultures so I posted this question here. Can you recommend another site for me?

Comment: I would suggest you bring it up in the chat room for the site. One problem with a question like this is that it helps you, but it doesn't have high potential to help others.

Comment: @simchona agree with you, I didn't know about chat room, thanks

Comment: I actually think this is on topic - the connotations of a word, and how that interacts with naming is nothing if not linguistic.

Comment: annyeong @Jungjoon - my nephew is married to a wonderful Korean woman!  I probably disagree with my two colleagues below.  **many parts of the english-speaking world are ridiculously ignorant about foreign languages** and on top of that **many parts of the english-speaking world love to make fun of anything where there is even the slightest chance of a 'silly' interpretation!**  I would advise against it.  Jae-nn is fantastic, but don't forget **Jae-in looks really beautiful in English** - it looks profound and awesome.  **Almost all names are common** so you shouldnt' worry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Both spellings are unconventional in US English and would not be readily associated with the pronunciation of *Jane*. While somewhat subjective, I think most people in the US would agree that the spelling *Jae-inn* is not ridiculous or funny looking. We use *ann*, *ynn*, and *anne* to end female names frequently, and it's not much different than those.

*Jae-motel* would be quite awkward though. The difference between *inn* and *motel* in the physical sense is only semantic, but in a name the difference is huge. And that's a subtlety a non-native speaker might not grasp, which is why your question makes sense.

There needs to be an IsThisAStupidBabyName.com and people need to use it! Kudos to you for checking first.

Comment: Many common names with ancient origins have real meanings which would be perceived as stupid if translated into English. I.e. Mr. Strongandhealthy Smith would be ridiculed beyond any belief. But Mr. Valentine Smith is completely fine. Still it doesnt change the fact that kids with unusual/silly names _will_ be ridiculed; parents do need to think more before comming up with "original" names. +1 for answer and +1 to jungjoon for asking

Comment: @Sejanus _Hollie Dae-inn_ would be awkward as well.

Answer (score 1):

Incorporated as part of another word like that, I don't think it would be a problem.

Children often look for ways to make fun of other children's names, so I certainly applaud you for being careful. I advise against any name where part of the name is something bad because it's likely that somewhere along the line some nasty kid will leap on it. Like if you're living in an English-speaking country and you were thinking of calling your child "Jae-moron", I'd say bad idea. No matter what that name means in your native language, kids here would notice in two seconds that it sounds like an insult and make fun of your child. But "inn"? Even if kids noticed that one syllable of your child's name is a word for "hotel", it wouldn't be very funny, and I doubt anyone would make anything of it, and if they did, your child could just shrug and say, "So what?"

When my wife and I were naming our children, we rejected several names we otherwise liked because they included syllables that sounded like vulgar words.

Comment: I agree with Jay, **be very cautious**. I encourage you that **Jae-in looks fantastic, to an English speaker**. I'd stick with that.

Answer (score 1):

If it is to be pronounced like *Jane*, why not drop the *i* before the double-n: *Jae-nn Kim*? That should resolve the issue, if it otherwise suits you.

I am not familiar with cultural matters, but generally it seems a nice way to spell a name and also pronounce it the same way. An unconventional (for Americans/ English speaking peoples) spelling can also be quite exotic and arouse curiosity.

Comment: this is a GREAT SUGGESTION.  nice work.